# error LoginPath cookie authentication .net 7.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am making authenticate cookie of login page, when you have not logged in and then go to the homepage, it will return the path as /User/Login, but when the web server runs, it returns the default path as /Account/Login even though I have add cookie with LoginPath="/User/Login" in program.cs. here is my code:

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(SystemConstants.MainConnectionString);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<WebShopDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/User/Login"; 
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/User/AccessDenied"; 
            });


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<LoginRequestValidator>()); ;

builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebShopDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserApiClient, UserApiClient>();

//add runtime
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
}
else
{
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
}

//builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
                //.AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<LoginRequestValidator>());

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();



app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
}
);

app.Run();
```

HomeController.cs

```
[Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
```

UserController.cs

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUserApiClient _userApiClient;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public UserController(IUserApiClient userApiClient, IConfiguration configuration) 
        {
            _userApiClient = userApiClient;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IActionResult Index() 
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginRequest request)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(ModelState);

            var token = await _userApiClient.Authenticate(request); 

            var userPrincipal = this.ValidateToken(token);
            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
                IsPersistent = false
            };
         
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                        userPrincipal,
                        authProperties);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        }

        private ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string jwtToken)
        {
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

            SecurityToken validatedToken;
            TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters();

            validationParameters.ValidateLifetime = true;

            validationParameters.ValidAudience = _configuration["Tokens:Issuer"];
            validationParameters.ValidIssuer = _configuration["Tokens:Issuer"];
            validationParameters.IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Tokens:Key"]));

            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(jwtToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);

            return principal;
        }
    }
```

Login.cshtml

```
<form asp-action="Login" asp-controller="User" method="post" class="user">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input asp-for="Username" type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" placeholder="Enter UserName">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox small">
                                                <input asp-for="RememberMe" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                                                <label class="custom-control-label">Remember Me</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Login</button>
                                    </form>
```

error in .net 7.0

i am trying to change the path /Account/Login to /User/Login but I cannot.
this is my first time posting, if something is wrong or you notice missing code, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identity is based on Cookie Authetication,You could press F12 and check the AddIdentity Method

```
public static IdentityBuilder AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>(
            this IServiceCollection services,
            Action<IdentityOptions> setupAction)
            where TUser : class
            where TRole : class
        {
            // Services used by identity
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, o =>
            {
                o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
                o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync
                };
            })
            .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme, o =>
            {
                o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
                o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            })
            .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme, o =>
            {
                o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme;
                o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidateAsync<ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator>
                };
            })
            .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme, o =>
            {
                o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme;
                o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            });

            // Hosting doesn't add IHttpContextAccessor by default
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            // Identity services
            services.TryAddScoped<IUserValidator<TUser>, UserValidator<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordValidator<TUser>, PasswordValidator<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordHasher<TUser>, PasswordHasher<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
            services.TryAddScoped<IRoleValidator<TRole>, RoleValidator<TRole>>();
            // No interface for the error describer so we can add errors without rev'ing the interface
            services.TryAddScoped<IdentityErrorDescriber>();
            services.TryAddScoped<ISecurityStampValidator, SecurityStampValidator<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator, TwoFactorSecurityStampValidator<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TRole>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<IUserConfirmation<TUser>, DefaultUserConfirmation<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<UserManager<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<SignInManager<TUser>>();
            services.TryAddScoped<RoleManager<TRole>>();

            if (setupAction != null)
            {
                services.Configure(setupAction);
            }

            return new IdentityBuilder(typeof(TUser), typeof(TRole), services);
        }
```

Try configure as below after you've called AddIdentity:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(op => op.LoginPath = "yourpath");
```

There're two schemes in your app,when you authenticate, you need to notice current scheme